# How do I check if my template class is a specific classtype?

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

In my function template, I'm trying to check whether the type `T` is a specific type. How would I do that?

```
template<class T> int foo(T a) {
  // check if T of type, say, String?
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want the "template specification way" ?

Comment: Use the "template overloading way" :)

Comment: You probably should check for behavior, not type.

Comment: hmm because I had a large portion of same code until the 'specification' part.

Comment: You are using templates the wrong way if you need to check the type of T. I think you should reconsider your approach.

Comment: @huy : why don't you keep the large portion of common code and call another complementary function which you can specialize for specific type-based code ?

Comment: Exactly. Like @visitor showed. I think his way is very nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose you could use the [`std::type_info`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info) returned by the typeid operator

Comment: Warning: runtime check. As such, you cannot rely on compile-time properties. E.g. you can't just use `operator[]` after checking if T==std::string.

Comment: @huy It’s usually better to do static checks for types instead of runtime checks. Thus, `std::is_same`, `std::is_convertible`, or similar. Then you can avoid the runtime cost of checking the type. Instead, if only part of your code needs to know the type, use `if constexpr` (C++17) or a helper function; if all your code does, use function overloading.

Answer (score 50):

Instead of checking for the type use specializations. Otherwise, don't use templates.

```
template<class T> int foo(T a) {
      // generic implementation
}
template<> int foo(SpecialType a) {
  // will be selected by compiler 
}

SpecialType x;
OtherType y;
foo(x); // calls second, specialized version
foo(y); // calls generic version
```

Comment: It’s often a bad idea to specialize function templates; partial specialization isn’t supported, and if you mix specialization and overloading you often get unexpected results. Just overload from the beginning.

Answer (score 15):

If you don't care about compile-time, you may use [boost::is_same](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_same.html).

```
bool isString = boost::is_same<T, std::string>::value;
```

As of C++11, this is now part of the standard library

```
bool isString = std::is_same<T, std::string>::value
```

Comment: For the record: [is_same](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) is now part of the standard library.

Comment: "If you don't care about compile-time" Do you mean the time taken to compile the code, or being able to detect the 'sameness' at compile time?

Answer (score 11):

> hmm because I had a large portion of
>   same code until the 'specification'
>   part.

You can use overloading, but if a large part of the code would work for any type, you might consider extracting the differing part into a separate function and overload that.

```
template <class T>
void specific(const T&);

void specific(const std::string&);

template <class T>
void something(const T& t)
{
    //code that works on all types
    specific(t);
    //more code that works on all types
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I suspect someone should tell you why it might not be a good idea to avoid using overloading or specialization. Consider:

```
template<class T> int foo(T a) {
  if(isAString<T>()) {
    return a.length();
  } else {
    return a;
  }
}
```

You might think on a first sight that it will work for `int` too, because it will only try to call `length` for strings. But that intuition is wrong: The compiler still checks the string branch, even if that branch is not taken at runtime. And it will find you are trying to call a member function on non-classes if `T` is an int.

That's why you should separate the code if you need different behavior. But better use overloading instead of specialization, since it's easier to get a clue how things work with it.

```
template<class T> int foo(T a) {
  return a;
}

int foo(std::string const& a) {
  return a.length();
}
```

You have also better separated the code for different paths of behavior. It's not all anymore clued together. Notice that with overloading, the parameters may have different type forms and the compiler will still use the correct version if both match equally well, as is the case here: One can be a reference, while the other can not.

Comment: I encountered the issue you mentioned earlier, thats why I wanted to find a way to fix, but without overloading or class specialization. I didn't think of the 'get a clue how things will work' part. Will reconsider it, thanks!

Comment: Modifying your example with a cast would do the trick. But it would still not be my favorite solution :)

Comment: @Ben, what trick do you mean? And where to insert a cast? Do you mean to write `reinterpret_cast<string*>(&i)->length()` ? I agree that would be **very** ugly. And it will still fail in the other branch if `T` is `std::string`, because it can't convert it to `int` (return type). Not anywhere near my favorite solution either :) Best to overload or specialize it.

Comment: I assume what he meant is to apply typeid with typecasting and if-condition?

Comment: That’s what C++17 `if constexpr` is for

Comment: @DanielH Unfortunately `if constexpr` was not around at the time this answer was written. So it would be more correct to say "`if constexpr` can _now_ be used to make the first example valid". Though perhaps that should be another answer altogether instead of a mere comment?

Answer (score 4):

You can check using [`type_traits` (available in Boost and TR1)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_base_of.html) (e.g. `is_same` or `is_convertible`) if you really want to avoid specialization.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform static checks on the type that you have received (look at the boost type traits library), but unless you use specialization (or overloads, as @litb correctly points out) at one point or another, you will not be able to provide different specific implementations depending on the argument type.

Unless you have a particular reason (which you could add to the question) not to use the specialization in the interface just do specialize.

```
template <> int subtract( std::string const & str );
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using C++11 or later, std::is_same does exactly what you want:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr bool IsFloat() { return std::is_same<T, float>::value; }

template <typename T>
void SomeMethodName() {
  if (IsFloat<T>()) {
    ...
  }
}
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same

Answer (score 1):

You can check if two types are the same with the [`std::is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) trait:

```cpp
template<class T>
void foo(T a) {
    // C++17
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, String>) { /* ... */ }
    // C++11
    if (std::is_same<T, String>::value) { /* ... */ }
}
```

#### Constraints on a function

In C++20, there is also the [`std::same_as`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/same_as) concept:

```cpp
// use the concept as a type constraint here
template <std::same_as<String> T>
void foo(T a);

// or with abbreviated function templates
void foo(std::same_as<String> auto a);
```

This would prevent you from calling a function with any type other than `A`.
Note that `std::enable_if` can also emulate such C++20 type constraints.
Checking whether the type is the same *inside* the function doesn't affect overload resolution.

#### Checking the dynamic type

Note that neither of the solutions above check the *dynamic* type, i.e. they don't account for polymorphic classes. This would require [`typeid`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid):

```cpp
if (typeid(a) == typeid(String))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use C++20 concepts like this:

```
template<typename T>
concept SpecialType = std::is_same_v<T, String>;
```

then you can have another function:

```
template<SpecialType T>
void foo(T t) {}
```

which only accepts templates which statisfy the concept above.